# casting a void-pointer to a struct- pointer (in a function call)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

I have a header file, (lets call it gen.h) which contains the following line:

```
typedef void* pNode;
SampleFunction(PNode node); /* just a function for example*/
```

Now, lets say I have another source file (part.c), and it contains  the following struct:

```
typdef struct _OBJ* POBJ;
typdef struct _OBJ
{
    double xi;
    double xf;
    double yi;
    double yf;
    int key;
}
```

I want to send a pointer to the struct (PBOJ) as a parameter to a function (lets say SampleFunction)  that is expecting to get a pointer to void type (pNode); so how do I do this?

Comment: Did you try just passing the pointer to the function? Also `pNode != PNode`

Comment: Casts to and from `void *` are implicit in C; you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: That said, hiding pointers behind typedefs is usually considered bad practice, because it obscures what's going on here.

Comment: @self I meant to write pNode, PNode is just a typo. I didn't try this yet (passing pobj without casting ), I didn't finish my code yet. so you guys say that I can simply do: SampleFunction (pobj) (when pobj is a pointer to the struct), without casting or anything?

Comment: @user2750466 Yes. The C standard guarantees that any pointer can be converted to/from a void pointer. You could pass a `char *********` and there would be no need for a cast. Of course, I would hope this function is documented with some info about what it expects and what it will do. Anything beyond that is unspecified behaviour and should be avoided of course.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune, if I do as you say, will I be capable of getting to all the fields of pobj?? (I can't handle casting in the called function)

Comment: @user2750466 As long as the function doesn't try deallocating the object or any of its members, yes, you can get all of the fields of pobj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is just a simple sample, so I did not write to init, delete, etc.

```
struct _OBJ
{
  double xi;
  double xf;
  double yi;
  double yf;
  int key;
}; 

typedef struct _OBJ* POBJ;

typedef void* pNode;

void SampleFunction(pNode node)
{
  //null check  
  if(node == NULL)
  {
    //error
  }

  //Do Something
  // ...

}; /* just a function for example*/

int main()
{
  POBJ obj = new _OBJ;
  SampleFunction((pNode)obj);
  delete obj;
}
```

Comment: I can't change SampleFunction, SampleFunction doesn't know what is the type we might send to it, so I need to do the casting from the calling function.

Comment: @user2750466 I've edited above code. As rullof said, you've already typedef `void*` to `pNode`,so `void*` and `pNode` are exactly same. Even if you just write as`SampleFunction(obj)` without typecast, it is also good.

Comment: `new` and `delete` do not exist in C. Also there is no need to cast `obj` in C.

Comment: @CodeDreamer You have to use `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete` because they are only `c++`

Answer (score 0):

You just cast it to `PNode` like any other type as `void*` can point to any other type safely.

Since PBOJ is a pointer to _OBJ you cast it directly without the `&` operator

```
POBJ Ptr;
SampleFunction((PNode)Ptr);
// or SampleFunction((void *)Ptr);
```

Comment: But pNode itself is void * !

Comment: @user2750466 So what's the problem you can use `(void *)Ptr` or `(PNode)Ptr` there is no difference.

Comment: @user2750466 You will have to cast the the pointer `node` it again to POBJ since you cannot dereference a `void *` then you can access them by `castedPtr->member`

Comment: but I'm not allowed to handle this in SampleFunction

Comment: SampleFunction may be used to other types of pointers (int, cahr) , the type of obj can be anything...

Comment: `void *` can point to any type but to dereference it you must cast it again to the original type. What part of this is not clear?